# Connect to SQL Server database using jsp?

Tags: sql-server

Here is some code inside my jsp:

```
try {
    String connectionURL = "jdbc:sqlserver://10.103.18.174:3304;databaseName=DWH_ILEM";

    Connection connection = null;

    Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver").newInstance();

    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "dwh_reader", "ilem@2017");

    if(!connection.isClosed()) {
        out.println("Successfully connected");
        connection.close();
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        out.println("Unable");
    }
}
```

And here is the structure of my project:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7x5F.jpg

I can connect to the database via SSMS but not with jdbc, I can't detect what is wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest to replace `out.println("Unable");` with `throw ex;` so to see what the problem is.

Comment: @MaximKreschishin Here is the result: https://imgur.com/a/ypPoB ; The program doesnt detect drivers?

Comment: As it seems it is. The libraries that web-application uses must be in the "lib" directory of the project. Did you put the jdbc-driver there?

Comment: @MaximKreschishin Yes and I have the same error.

Comment: @MaximKreschishin Here are all the files in the lib directory, maybe something is missing? https://imgur.com/a/WGEih

Comment: Are you sure your "lib" directory is situated inside your project's WEB-INF directory? Otherwise it looks allright.

Comment: @MaximKreschishin I moved it to WEB-INF with no results.

Comment: Try to erase one of the mssql-jdbc-6.2.1.jre.jar files. For example if you are using java8 than remove mssql-jdbc-6.2.1.jre7.jar file and leave only mssql-jdbc-6.2.1.jre8.jar.

Comment: @MaximKreschishin Same problem, are you sure the issue is with jdbc?

Comment: The problem, I suppose, with line `Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver").newInstance();` as it can't find the driver and throws java.lang.ClassNotFoundException. As a possibility, you can comment that line of code and see where it gets.

Comment: @MaximKreschishin https://imgur.com/a/c9ciX here is the result

Comment: Judging by this result it is definitely that your web-application can't find driver-class com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver. So it doesn't see jdbc jar files.